# Dynamically pass column position in awk command to replace that specific column with a constant value

Tags: awk

I am new to scripting and have requirement where I need to dynamically pass column number and replace only that column value with a constant string for all records.

Below is what I tried, but looks like syntax error. I am struggling to pass the value of  Column position to variable `pos` in the second part.

second part what I meant is  `${$pos}} { ${$pos}="XXXX"}`

```
Columnpos=3
while read  
do
    awk -F"|" -v OFS="|"  -v pos=$Columnpos  '${$pos}} { ${$pos}="XXXX"}  1' >  $Outile
done <"$InpFile"
```

tried some other option like   `$[$pos]} { $[$pos]="XXXX"}` , but no luck

I have searched for the same topic and could find some related to this, but didn't find anything matching my requirement.

Comment: Thanks Ed for the advice and suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 var=2
 awk -v "col=${var}" '{print $col}'  random.file
```

seems to work for me.

(edit for follow up note)
replacement is just what you were already sort of doing:

```
'{$col="XXX";print}'
```

Comment: Thanks tomc!,  your command help to print that column, that working for me as well.  I want to do the replacement. what command I use to do the replacement which I need?  can you please  include that as well? that is the place where I am failing

Comment: Thank you, its working. wasn't familiar with how does print command  works!

Comment: print prints what you tell it. if you don't tell it anything then it prints the default  variable $0. which is the current row made up of $1 $2 $3 ...  if you change one of the variables $n  that change will be seen in $0.   hope that helps.